# xmlstarlet to insert tags

Tags: xmlstarlet

I am using the command:

`xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl --subnode "/boinc" --type elem -n app -v "" project_00.xml > project_01.xml`

However, I would like to insert two more tags into that one:

```
<app>
 <name>name</name>
 <nikname>nikname</nikname>
</app>
```

In my `project_00.xml`, I already have others tag app and it is causing conflicts.

The problem with this command:

```
xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/boinc" --type elem -n app -v "" project_00.xml|     xmlstarlet ed --subnode //app --type elem -n name -v "newApp"| xmlstarlet ed --subnode //app --type elem -n user_friendly_name -v "New.App" > project_01.xml
```

is that it created this.:

```
  <app name="wilson">
    <name>wilson</name>
    <user_friendly_name>Mr.Wilson</user_friendly_name>
    <name>newApp</name>
    <user_friendly_name>New.App</user_friendly_name>
  </app>
  <app>
    <name>newApp</name>
    <user_friendly_name>New.App</user_friendly_name>
  </app>
```

Does know the exactly command?

I tried this command but it replicated the  to all app tags

```
xmlstarlet ed -s "/boinc" -t elem -n app -v "" -s "/boinc/app" -t elem -n name -v "name" -s "/boinc/app" -t elem -n user_friendly_name -v "New.App" project_00.xml > project_01.xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need an XPath expression to match the node you just inserted; since `--subnode` always puts new children in last place you can use `/boinc/app[last()]`:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  --subnode /boinc --type elem -n app -v '' \
  --subnode '/boinc/app[last()]' --type elem -n name -v newApp \
  --subnode '/boinc/app[last()]' --type elem -n user_friendly_name -v New.App \
  project_00.xml > project_01.xml
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked perfectly! I really appreciate your reply :) I was staked on this for 1 day.